# geojson or shapes of ADM3 in all countries in the world

Tags: shapefile, data, geojson

Where or how can I get the ADM3 geojson or shapes for all the countries in the world?

I am new in Dataviz and I tried geonames.org but I only get points and not polygons.

ADM3 is the 3rd category of country division. So for instance in the case of USA, it is ADM0 = Country, ADM1 = State, ADM2 = County, etc..

Comment: What is ADM3?  I think this may be better suited as two separate questions 1) How can I get polygons for all countries of the world? and 2) How can a import/display polygons in python using X library?

Comment: Good idea, I am going to change it now

Comment: I've only seen sporadic ADM2 data, and have **NEVER** seen ADM3 data.  If you have nothing, you have all there is.

Comment: For open data I think the best place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

According to paper [Map Methodology 2016 - NTD Mapping Tool](http://www.ntdmap.org/dwnlds/NTD%20Map%20Methodology.pdf) one source of third-order administrative regions (admin3) is:

[Geoconnect: A harmonized source of district-level geography for neglected tropical disease programs.](http://www.geoconnect.org/)

The World Food Programme also gives access to *Administrative Boundaries Level 3* data through [WFPGeoNode](http://geonode.wfp.org/search/?category__identifier__in=boundaries&limit=10&offset=0&title__icontains=boundaries%20level%203)

Answer (score 0):

https://gadm.org/ has a downloadable collection. Has level 3 some countries as far as i can tell. Sometimes also level 4 & 5 available.

In [this github repo](https://github.com/stephanietuerk/admin-boundaries) you can find an almost complete scrape.